# Django - django-registration with LDAP

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-registration

I'm currently using Django with the [django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/) package.
This one give my users the ability to sign in among other things.
Now I'd like to be able to use an LDAP authentication backend like [django-auth-ldap](http://packages.python.org/django-auth-ldap/)

Will my users still be able to register online ?

Can someone point me to the right direction to properly configure the ldap backend ?
(tutorial or doc links)